# Get IV size for a specific cipher in node.js

Tags: node.js, cryptography

Is there a way to get the IV size for a specific cipher, like what is returned by a call to OpenSSL's EVP_CIPHER_CTX_iv_length()?

If an IV has the wrong size, cypto.createCipheriv() will return an error, but there does not seem to exist a function returning the right size before attempting to create a cipher based on an IV.

Comment: The size of the IV largely depends on the mode of operation (and block size). Quite commonly it is a static value, so you can just make it a constant. Some modes have multiple possible IV sizes (GCM for instance allows for any sized nonce as IV). Personally I don't believe in switching modes of operation without making at least some adjustments to the calling code, so you might as well program it in. I agree it is slightly annoying if this functionality it is missing - and it certainly looks that way.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from node v15, one can use [getCipherInfo](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptogetcipherinfonameornid-options) :

> crypto.getCipherInfo(cipher).ivLength